# Searching GitHub pull requests with a logic OR operator on fields, not values

Tags: github

GitHub supports a logical OR operator for values of a single field, like `label:one,two,three`. But, I can't find a way to use any kind of OR operator for different fields.

Specifically, I'm looking for `reviewed-by:myuser OR assignee:myuser`

Is this possible today?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How to search with logic operators on GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57933)